# What was the first arc to explore a major superhero death?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero

What was the first story arc to explore a major superhero death?

To avoid broad interpretations:

1. By superheroes I also mean the ones with or without superpowers just like Young Allies, Batman, Bucky Barnes, Rocketeer / etc.
2. By story arc to explore I mean the ones that is the target of the history it self. Example: Death of Captain Mar-Vell, Superman Death, Barry Allen. **NOT**: uncle Ben **nor** Thomas Wayne and Martha Wayne.
3. By death I mean also the ones that maybe alive in alternative universes or reborn after a good time in the refrigerator.

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/when-we-first-met-who-was-the-first-superhero-to-die-in-the-line-of-duty/

Comment: @VarunNair that solved my question. Thanks

Comment: The first link I posted might also interest you, if you have the time :)

Comment: I was about to say that. The Comet was the first super hero to die in comics not Captain Marvel

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic wrong. from wiki: "We learn later, in The Crucible, that he didn't die, but resumed human form and became a baseball player named Jay Cole with no memory of his earlier life."

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel Thats the one from  DC Comics' Impact Comics series, The Comet. The character is loosely based on the Archie Comics character, The Comet. It was published in July 1991. I was talking about Impact Comics one from 1940. This one was revived but after 20 years in October, 1964 than again in 1966 and 1983 possibly to renew copyright and ownership of the character

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic but officially he was not dead, just like Bucky Barnes.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel No he was really dead. He was revived with a new costume and extraterrestrial origins as a love interest for Fly Girl in Adventures of the Fly #30 (October, 1964). So they took old name and gave him whole new origin and interests. John Dickering the original Comet is dead and he is still dead as such.    Besides the question was "By death I mean also the ones that maybe alive in alternative universes or reborn after a good time in the refrigerator." and I think 23 years in "refrigerator" is enough to have Comet as valid answer